# Whichever vs any with numerics

Tags: grammar, uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

- Here's a list of games. You can buy whichever you want.
- Here's a list of games. You can buy any you want.

I, as a non-native speaker, understand it as:

- The first sentence means that only one game can be bought.
- The second sentence means that any amount of fames can be bought.

But the problem starts with the use of any with an amount.

- You can buy whichever 3 you want.
- You can buy any 3 you want.

Are both sentences grammatically correct?

Here are more examples with the word **amount**:

- Here's the sack of sugar. You can take whichever amount is needed. (Is **whatever** also possoble?)
- Here's the sack of sugar. You can take any amount is needed. (This sounds really bad to my ear)

Comment: *Whichever* strongly implies *[one] choice from a **finite, contextually-known** list of choices*, so it's not very appropriate in the "sugar" example unless you've got a list of possible quantities you expect the customer to choose from. Your final *You can take any amount is needed* is simply ungrammatical, but you can just delete ***is*** to fix it.

Comment: Personally, I feel like you're missing "one" as in, the correct sentences should be: You can buy whichever one(s) you want. Meanwhile, you could also say, "You can buy however much/many you want. You can buy as many/as much as you want." And grammatically, it's not wrong to say, "You can take any amount needed (necessary)," but I think it would be more idiomatic to say, "You can take however much is necessary/you need."